# Mysql CURDATE() not work in 12:00AM-1:30AM

Tags: mysql

I need to get the number of record that inserted today (12:00:00 AM - 11:59:59 PM)
I wrote this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM viewlog2 where DATE(time)=CURDATE()
```

It's OK! But At midnight (12:00 AM - 1:30 AM Approximately) this return the previous day record's count and Despite adding new records to table, it will not be shown in count.
Is there any better way to get all records that inserted today (12:00:00 AM - 11:59:59 PM)?

Comment: can you use `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE()`?

Comment: @lucumt What is the difference?

Comment: seems to be a time difference between your system and mysql time. Is mysql running on your system or in other machine (server)? If the code that's inserting the data and your database both are available on same machine then it shouldn't be a problem. Still try to find if there is any time difference between the two.